# Linear regression coefficient

Tags: linear-regression

I'm studying linear regression with *Draper's Applying regression analysis* book
There is a formula for coefficient b1 which is clear to me:

$$
b_{1}= \frac{n\sum x_{i}y_{i}-\sum x_{i}\sum y_{i}}{n\sum x_{i}^2 - \sum x_{i}\sum x_{i}}
$$
What I can't understand is how to get this one:
$$
b_{1}= \frac{\sum  \left (X_{i}-\overline{X}  \right )\left (Y_{i}-\overline{Y}  \right )}{\sum \left ( X_{i}-\overline{X} \right )^2}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum  \left (X_{i}-\overline{X}  \right )\left (Y_{i}-\overline{Y}  \right )=\sum X_i Y_i-(\sum X_i) \overline{Y}-\overline{X}
(\sum Y_i)+n\overline{X}\overline{Y}$. Thus 
$\sum  \left (X_{i}-\overline{X}  \right )\left (Y_{i}-\overline{Y}  \right)=\sum X_i Y_i-n\overline{X}\overline{Y}$. Using this also for $X=Y$ the second expression reads as
$\displaystyle\frac{\sum X_i Y_i-n\overline{X}\overline{Y}}{\sum X_i^2-n\overline{X}^2}$. Multiplying both, nominator and denominator, with $n$ gives the first expression for $b_1$.

Comment: How have you eliminated 2nd and 3rd components?

Comment: $\sum X_i=n \overline{X}$ and similarly for $Y$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger When you expand and open the brackets, how does an n come in the third component?

Comment: $\sum  \left (X_{i}-\overline{X}  \right )\left (Y_{i}-\overline{Y}  \right)$ $=\sum \left(X_i Y_i-\overline{X} Y_i-X_i\overline{Y}+\overline{X}\overline{Y}\right)$